# DNS: How to resolve multiple records from DNS NAPTR RR

Tags: linux, dns, sip

Please help me in understanding the below DNS issue. This is regarding SIP interaction with DNS.

When a DNS query is made to a domain (say abc.com) and we are returned two NAPTR RR responses.

```
abc.com IN NAPTR 20 30 "s" "SIP+D2U" "" _sip._udp.myabc
abc.com IN NAPTR 20 20 "s" "SIP+D2U" "" _sip._udp.myxyz
```

Now one of the record will be given preference and selected. If the record which is selected (say _sip._udp.myabc) has failed (network not reachable) then should the second record also be tried? Or we will look for the backup of the first one?

RR - Resource Record.

Please answer and/or share the link which has any information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer I have received from an off forum discussion (with colleague).

The DNS discovery proceeds as -

```
1 - First one of the NAPTR record will be selected (based on preference rules).
2 - For this NAPTR record we will do an SRV query.
3 - Now each record in the SRV response will be tried one by one untill we receives a positive response.
```

Please correct if wrong.